# Advancing a timestamp by a day when an exception is encountered

Tags: c#

In my code, I am able to delete dated files from a folder.

But the date must appear in certain `*.dat` files, otherwise nothing happens.

Some days are not included in these files; for example, holidays are skipped.

In this case I am encountering a problem.

So, if I am on one of these days, how can I advance to the next day after failing?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Destinationdead = "C:\\test\\test1";

        string todaysDate;
        todaysDate = dateTimePicker1.Text;
        int FinalDate4 = 0;

        BLWriterClass writerdelete1 = new BLWriterClass();

        writerdelete1.OpenDirectory(Destinationdead);
        writerdelete1.OpenSecurityBySymbol(SecSymbol);
        FinalDate4 = int.Parse(todaysDate);

        {
            try
            {
                writerdelete1.OpenDirectory(Destinationdead);
                writerdelete1.OpenSecurityBySymbol(SecSymbolbol);
                FinalDate4 = int.Parse(todaysDate);

                writerdelete1.OpenDirectory(Destinationdead);
                writerdelete1.OpenSecurityBySymbol(SecSymbol);
                int idate = Convert.ToInt32(dateTimePicker1.Text);
                int itodate = Convert.ToInt32(dateTimePicker2.Text);
                writerdelete1.DeleteSecRecords(idate, itodate);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
        writerdelete1.CloseSecurity();
        writerdelete1.CloseDirectory();
    }
```

Comment: According to your question if there is the date which is not exist then how to possible delete that date record!! And you should check the error in catch() block.

Comment: I means If the Selcted  date ,is not In the Datfile, its go skip and find next aviable to date. that logic i needs, Hope u understand

Comment: Ok you mean that if the sunday is holiday and no record for that date then it should skip this day and check for next day Monday. M I right?

Comment: Yes Sir , May be now u got my point

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `DeleteSecRecords` method.

Google shows no hits for this name, so there is no way to look at it to further analyze the problem.

---

*Edit:* Ah, I understand what you are asking for. This will advance to the next day whenever an exception is encountered, until no possible days remain.

```
int idate = Convert.ToInt32(dateTimePicker1.Text);
int itodate = Convert.ToInt32(dateTimePicker2.Text);

while (idate <= itodate) {
    try
    {
        writerdelete1.OpenDirectory(Destinationdead);
        writerdelete1.OpenSecurityBySymbol(SecSymbolbol);
        FinalDate4 = int.Parse(todaysDate);

        writerdelete1.OpenDirectory(Destinationdead);
        writerdelete1.OpenSecurityBySymbol(SecSymbol);
        writerdelete1.DeleteSecRecords(idate, itodate);

        break;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        idate += 60 * 60 * 24; // advance by one day
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u help me please I am new in c#

Comment: Are far as I can tell, the error is not in your code. The library you are using ("MetaLib", maybe?) seems to be causing the problem.

Comment: yes I am using  that DLL.If i Selected date is not that Dat file , then it must seek next Aviable date , then its not pblm .

Comment: english please? what the hell is 'pblm'? This is not a site where everybody might be fluent with SMS lingos.

Comment: hi,My problem is ,if the sunday is holiday and no record for that date then it should skip this day and check for next day Monday or Aviable date. From that date to Current date data needs delete.

Comment: I have updated my answer, does this fix your problem?